# Decimal issue with calculator

Tags: javascript

My calculator can't  keep long decimals within the output screen (i.e 1/3). I have tried to convert result into a number using `parseFloat` then use Math. round, then `toString` to convert back the result into string and display it on the screen, but it did not work. Please help!!!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var testNumLength = function(number) {
    if (number.length > 9) {
      totaldiv.text(number.substr(number.length - 9, 9));
      if (number.length > 15) {
        number = "";
        totaldiv.text("Err");
      }
    }
  };
  var entry = "";
  var current = ""; //after operator is entered
  var operator = "";
  var res = "";
  var totaldiv = $("#total");
  totaldiv.text("0");

  $("#numbers a").not("#clear,#clearall").click(function() {
    entry += $(this).text(); //take the text of the numbers when clicked and append it to var entry
    //display input1 on screen
    totaldiv.html(entry);
    testNumLength(entry);
  })

  $("#clear,#clearall").click(function() {
    entry = "";
    if ($(this).attr("id") === "clearall") {
      current = "";
    }
    totaldiv.text("0");

  })

  $("#operators a").click(function() {
    //append operators to var operator
    operator = $(this).text();

    current = entry;
    entry = "";


  })

  $("#decimal").click(function() {
    //var numOfDecs = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {

      if (entry.indexOf(".") == -1) {
        entry += ".";
        // numOfDecs += 1;
      }
    }
    totaldiv.text(entry);
    testNumLength(entry);
  })

  $("#equals").click(function() {
    var result = eval(current + operator + entry);
    entry = result;
    testNumLength(result);
    totaldiv.html(result);


  })

})
```

```css
body,
div,
a {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#calculator {
  width: 310px;
  height: 460px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: maroon;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#total {
  height: 70px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 60px;
}

#numbers,
#operators {
  margin: auto;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#operators a {
  display: block;
  width: 46px;
  height: 45px;
  float: left;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 39px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#EDEDED), to(#DCDCDC));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EDEDED, #DCDCDC);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#numbers a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  color: black;
  font-size: 43px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#EDEDED), to(#DCDCDC));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EDEDED, #DCDCDC);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#side {
  width: 49px;
  float: right;
}

#side a {
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  float: right;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#EDEDED), to(#DCDCDC));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EDEDED, #DCDCDC);
}

a#equals {
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="calculator">
    <div id="total">
    </div>
    <div id="operators">
      <a id="plus">+</a>
      <a id="minus">-</a>
      <a id="divide">/</a>
      <a id="times">*</a>

    </div>
    <div id="side">
      <a id="sq">^</a>
      <a id="sqrt">√</a>
      <a id="decimal">.</a>
      <a id="equals">=</a>
    </div>

    <div id="numbers">
      <a id="clear">C</a>
      <a id="clearall">AC</a>
      <a id=>1</a>
      <a>2</a>
      <a>3</a>
      <a>4</a>
      <a>5</a>
      <a>6</a>
      <a>7</a>
      <a>8</a>
      <a>9</a>
      <a>0</a>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `toFixed` to limit the number of digits after the decimal point. So `0.333333333333333` with `toFixed(2)` will return `0.33`.

In addition to that you need to account for the digits before the decimal. So you need to calculate the digits before the decimal point, and ensure that the length of the entire number does not exceed 9 digits. It can be done like so:

```
var integerPortionLength = result.toFixed(0).length;
totaldiv.html(result.toFixed(9 - integerPortionLength));
```

Here's the updated pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JrZKxd?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

`totaldiv.html(result.toFixed(6));`

Try to use `toFixed(n)`.

You can slice your result number.

Comment: Hey, that was my first guess as well. But you need to account for the digits before the decimal point as well. See the pen in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

- If it's about the display - change the div containing the output number (the "total") to have CSS style of "overflow:hidden"
- If it's about the way you handle numbers, you can round these numbers a bit. On Calculla we use simple approach: if you want numbers to be no longer than let's say 2 ciphers after comma (like 10.33 instead of unlimited 333333....) then to this:

  let outNumber = Math.round(inNumber * 100) / 100;

  It's not a perfect solution, but it's simple and generally works.
  This is a bit different in results from simply using "toFixed(2)", but I'll leave it to you to discover how.

Answer (score 0):

try  `toFixed()` method for that

`totaldiv.html(result.toFixed(2));`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var testNumLength = function(number) {
    if (number.length > 9) {
      totaldiv.text(number.substr(number.length - 9, 9));
      if (number.length > 15) {
        number = "";
        totaldiv.text("Err");
      }
    }
  };
  var entry = "";
  var current = ""; //after operator is entered
  var operator = "";
  var res = "";
  var totaldiv = $("#total");
  totaldiv.text("0");

  $("#numbers a").not("#clear,#clearall").click(function() {
    entry += $(this).text(); //take the text of the numbers when clicked and append it to var entry
    //display input1 on screen
    totaldiv.html(entry);
    testNumLength(entry);
  })

  $("#clear,#clearall").click(function() {
    entry = "";
    if ($(this).attr("id") === "clearall") {
      current = "";
    }
    totaldiv.text("0");

  })

  $("#operators a").click(function() {
    //append operators to var operator
    operator = $(this).text();

    current = entry;
    entry = "";


  })

  $("#decimal").click(function() {
    //var numOfDecs = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {

      if (entry.indexOf(".") == -1) {
        entry += ".";
        // numOfDecs += 1;
      }
    }
    totaldiv.text(entry);
    testNumLength(entry);
  })

  $("#equals").click(function() {
    var result = eval(current + operator + entry);
    entry = result;
    testNumLength(result);
    totaldiv.html(result.toFixed(2));


  })

})
```

```css
body,
div,
a {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#calculator {
  width: 310px;
  height: 460px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: maroon;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#total {
  height: 70px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 60px;
}

#numbers,
#operators {
  margin: auto;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#operators a {
  display: block;
  width: 46px;
  height: 45px;
  float: left;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 39px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#EDEDED), to(#DCDCDC));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EDEDED, #DCDCDC);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#numbers a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  color: black;
  font-size: 43px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#EDEDED), to(#DCDCDC));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EDEDED, #DCDCDC);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#side {
  width: 49px;
  float: right;
}

#side a {
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  float: right;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#EDEDED), to(#DCDCDC));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EDEDED, #DCDCDC);
}

a#equals {
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="calculator">
    <div id="total">
    </div>
    <div id="operators">
      <a id="plus">+</a>
      <a id="minus">-</a>
      <a id="divide">/</a>
      <a id="times">*</a>

    </div>
    <div id="side">
      <a id="sq">^</a>
      <a id="sqrt">√</a>
      <a id="decimal">.</a>
      <a id="equals">=</a>
    </div>

    <div id="numbers">
      <a id="clear">C</a>
      <a id="clearall">AC</a>
      <a id=>1</a>
      <a>2</a>
      <a>3</a>
      <a>4</a>
      <a>5</a>
      <a>6</a>
      <a>7</a>
      <a>8</a>
      <a>9</a>
      <a>0</a>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I just found out another problem. i can't keep chaining mathematical operations together until I hit the equal button. It only output the right result for 2 inputs at a time... How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

A CSS Only Solution

```
  #total {
      ....
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var testNumLength = function(number) {
    if (number.length > 9) {
      totaldiv.text(number.substr(number.length - 9, 9));
      if (number.length > 15) {
        number = "";
        totaldiv.text("Err");
      }
    }
  };
  var entry = "";
  var current = ""; //after operator is entered
  var operator = "";
  var res = "";
  var totaldiv = $("#total");
  totaldiv.text("0");

  $("#numbers a").not("#clear,#clearall").click(function() {
    entry += $(this).text(); //take the text of the numbers when clicked and append it to var entry
    //display input1 on screen
    totaldiv.html(entry);
    testNumLength(entry);
  })

  $("#clear,#clearall").click(function() {
    entry = "";
    if ($(this).attr("id") === "clearall") {
      current = "";
    }
    totaldiv.text("0");

  })

  $("#operators a").click(function() {
    //append operators to var operator
    operator = $(this).text();

    current = entry;
    entry = "";


  })

  $("#decimal").click(function() {
    //var numOfDecs = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {

      if (entry.indexOf(".") == -1) {
        entry += ".";
        // numOfDecs += 1;
      }
    }
    totaldiv.text(entry);
    testNumLength(entry);
  })

  $("#equals").click(function() {
    var result = eval(current + operator + entry);
    entry = result;
    testNumLength(result);
    totaldiv.html(result);


  })

})
```

```css
body,
div,
a {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#calculator {
  width: 310px;
  height: 460px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: maroon;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#total {
  height: 70px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#numbers,
#operators {
  margin: auto;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#operators a {
  display: block;
  width: 46px;
  height: 45px;
  float: left;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 39px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#EDEDED), to(#DCDCDC));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EDEDED, #DCDCDC);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#numbers a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  color: black;
  font-size: 43px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#EDEDED), to(#DCDCDC));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EDEDED, #DCDCDC);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#side {
  width: 49px;
  float: right;
}

#side a {
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  float: right;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#EDEDED), to(#DCDCDC));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EDEDED, #DCDCDC);
}

a#equals {
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="calculator">
    <div id="total">
    </div>
    <div id="operators">
      <a id="plus">+</a>
      <a id="minus">-</a>
      <a id="divide">/</a>
      <a id="times">*</a>

    </div>
    <div id="side">
      <a id="sq">^</a>
      <a id="sqrt">√</a>
      <a id="decimal">.</a>
      <a id="equals">=</a>
    </div>

    <div id="numbers">
      <a id="clear">C</a>
      <a id="clearall">AC</a>
      <a id=>1</a>
      <a>2</a>
      <a>3</a>
      <a>4</a>
      <a>5</a>
      <a>6</a>
      <a>7</a>
      <a>8</a>
      <a>9</a>
      <a>0</a>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```